# Mongoose query a populated field

Tags: mongoose, populate

```
   db.History.find({'_file.project': 'someproject' )
      .populate('_file', 'name reference project')
      .sort(sortField || '-created')
      .limit(max || 64)
      .exec(this);
```

Here I'm trying to find all documents which match on a populated field from the _file reference. Is doesn't seem to work. Is something like this possible at all?

I could duplicate the project field to this object, as a workaround just for querying but I'd rather not of course.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, a `find` query's conditions parameter can only reference the collection being queried.

`populate` is not a join, it's just a convenience function to follow up the main query with additional queries to pull in the associated data from other collections.

Comment: Thanks. So, just to be sure, in order to query the History collection based on project I will have to add the project field, duplicating it from the File model? Retrieving all documents and then filtering afterwards is not an option since the History collection is possibly very large.

Comment: @0x80 Right, or get all the `File` docs with matching `project` and then use an `$in` query against `History` using the `_id` values from the first query.

Comment: I get it now. It's good to know there are two options. Thanks!

Comment: This might have not existed when this was answered but the populate method supports a "match" property: ```populate({
    path: 'notes',
    match: /airline/,
    select: 'text',
    model: 'modelName'
    options: opts
  }).```. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-execPopulate

Comment: @DougMolineux The `match` option only controls which docs get their path populated after the main query completes. If the referenced doc doesn't match, the original reference id value remains unpopulated.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean! So it would not be relevant to the question, thank you

Comment: well, it could be ;). You could basically check after you get your result if your joined/matched dataset has been populated or not and remove it from your response