# MongoDB, only display objects in a collection where a status matches in another

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have 2 collections - competition and product. Competition contains the product `objectID` and product contains `competition_status`.

What I'm trying to do is ONLY display the competitions whose product has a `competition_status` of "Complete" or "Current".

I've implemented this, however, I am also seeing the competitions that had a "Pending" status, just the product objects is null for these two. I somehow need these competitions removed from the competitions object that is outputted.

```
api.mongo.competition.find(filter)
      .populate('product', 'name competition_status', { competition_status: { $in: ['Complete', 'Current'] } })


      .exec(
        function(err, competitions) {
          if(err) {
            next(err, {});
            return;
          }
          next(err, competitions);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
{ competition_status: { $nin: ['Pending'] }
```

instead of

```
{ competition_status: { $in: ['Complete', 'Current'] }
```

you can get more info here [$nin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)

from [populate as join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535587/mongoose-query-a-populated-field)
populate is not a join, it's just a convenience function to follow up the main query with additional queries to pull in the associated data from other collections. You need to have

```
{ competition_status: { $in: ['Complete', 'Current'] }
```

in

mongo.competition.find()

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Won't this just adjust the "in"/"not in"? Seems as though the current way I have it where I use `populate` doesn't work?

Comment: Have you mapped the  competition and product.  this link might help http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html  i guess you are missing the mapping.