# Finding Mongoose subdocument by time updated

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have two Mongoose Schemas:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({  
    trade: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Trade'
    }
});

var Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

and

```
var TradeSchema = new Schema({
    expiresOn: {
        type: Date
    }
});

var Trade = mongoose.model('Trade', TradeSchema);
```

I am trying to use Item.find() to find a item if its trade date is less than the date the user passes in via the query string in the request. I'm using the following code:

```
if (req.query.expiresBefore) {
    Item.find({
        'trade.expiresOn': {
            $lte: req.query.expiresBefore
        }
    }, function (err, trades) {
        console.log(trades)
    })
}
```

However, I am receiving an empty array on the console.log() call. Using $gte also returns an empty array (though my research tells me that I need to use $lte for my purposes). What do I need to do to find the item document by matching the property (expiresOn) of its child (Trade)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to this one [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535587/mongoose-query-a-populated-field), what you want to do is not possible.I am not sure why you set the schemas like this, but if you want to keep them as they are. I would suggest you make a little change like the following

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({  
    trade: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Trade'
    }
});

var Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

and

```
var TradeSchema = new Schema({
    itemId: { //add this
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Item'
    },
    expiresOn: {
        type: Date
    }
});

var Trade = mongoose.model('Trade', TradeSchema);
```

---

```
if (req.query.expiresBefore) {
    Trade.
        find({
            'expiresOn': {
                $lte: req.query.expiresBefore
            }
        }).
        populate('itemId').
        exec(function (err, trades) {
            console.log(trades)
        });
}
```